# In the TV show Gotham, who is Kris Kringle?

Tags: dc, character-identification, gotham

In the TV show Gotham you get to see where a lot of the classic Batman villains get their start. I can't figure out who Kris Kringle is going to become, though. I'm not all that familiar with Batman canon, but from my searches I haven't been able to get a solid answer. Maybe someone here knows?

[image]

Comment: Santa Clause... I couldn't resist...

Comment: Apparently there *is* a very bad Santa in Batman canon.

Comment: I don't think anyone knows (apart from the people who work on the show), but you can see some speculations [here](http://www.bustle.com/articles/61801-who-is-kristen-kringle-on-gotham-dc-comics-may-hold-the-key-to-her-next-storyline).

Comment: @TGnat It's Odin in his Santa Claus aspect. ;)

Comment: I am more into Harley quin kind of side kick of riddler. Its better the Santa's daughter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As of Season 2 Episode 6, "Rise of the Villains: By Fire":

> She's dead, suffocated by Nygma, which means that, outside of resurrection, she's not going to be revealed as anything from the comics.

These circumstances, of course, [don't always rule out the character becoming someone](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Catwoman_%28Michelle_Pfeiffer%29), but only time will tell.

Comment: Note that a mousey secretary was killed by her boss in the second Michael Keaton/Tim Burton Batman movie.  She was played by Michelle Pfeiffer, and became Catwoman after her apparent death.

Comment: That is true. I suppose we'll just have to update as we get more information.

Comment: Isn't though catwoman already defined who it is / will become inside that one series?

Comment: @Thomas: Yes. But, I figured I'd might as well give a nod to the fact that it wouldn't be the first time a minor character has been killed and has come back, as per Wad's suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

[An article on bustle.com](https://www.bustle.com/articles/61801-who-is-kristen-kringle-on-gotham-dc-comics-may-hold-the-key-to-her-next-storyline) has some theories. It is quoted below.

As far as the show is concerned, Kristen Kringle works with Edward Nygma (who will eventually become the Riddler, E-Nygma, crafty isn't it?) at the Gotham City Police Department as an archivist, and the latter seems to have developed some romantic feelings towards her. As the article on bustle.com points out

> Though Kristen has acted solely as a love interest for Edward so far, the Gotham writers must have something more in store for her.

Possible outcomes:

- She’ll be Turning Into Harley Quinn

> The Hollywood Reporter suggested the possibility of [Kris turning into Harley Quinn](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/gotham-central-five-questions-spirit-744355), a character who debuted in the Batman comics as a [female sidekick to the Joker](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Harley_Quinn).

But this may necessarily not be the case here, as she is introduced as a counterpart (so far) of Riddler in the show and not Joker, and Joker has not even made an entry in *Gotham* so far.

- She’s Santa Claus’ Daughter

Well, we have seen Santa share the page with the Dark Knight before ([kind of](http://blog.timesunion.com/comicbooks/wanted-santa-claus-dead-or-alive/597/)) and he wasn’t

> the jolly old soul he’s portrayed to be in popular culture. Instead, he had an army of elves and was decapitated by intergalactic bounty hunter Lobo. Observer suggests that [Kris could be Santa's daughter](http://observer.com/2014/10/gotham-reference-guide-1x5-accentuate-the-postitive/).

[image]

- She’s Related To Mr. Freeze

Now this is a rather long shot. It's

> along the same lines as the Santa Claus theory, because Kringle = Santa = North Pole = Mr. Freeze.

But then again, these are as much as we can come up with at this point of time.

[image]

Comment: Harley Quinn didn't debut in the comics, plus she already has a backstory that would fit the mood of Gotham and couldn't descend from Miss Kringle's character, PLUS they don't have the same name. The only possible similarity between the two is their colouring and glasses.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this interview with Chelsea Spack in the [following interview](http://www.givememyremote.com/remote/2015/01/26/gotham-chelsea-spack-on-kristin-kringles-complicated-relationship-with-edward-nygma/) with Marissa Roffman on January 26, 2015 will help clear things up:

> **Since she, seemingly, is not a part of the DC Comics universe, do you have any theories about who this woman ultimately is?** 
> *CS:* I’m so fascinated, and I love playing her so much, because there’s so much potential; her story is virtually unwritten, so she could go anywhere. She’s mysterious, and she’s brilliant, and she private, and there’s so much that can unfold from that. The fact that she’s tied to Edward leaves a lot of potential. I’m excited and thrilled to see where she goes. I have my theories about what I would love to see, but I don’t know! She’s not in the comics! We get to see where she goes.